# Command that does different things based on whether something is selected

Tags: key-bindings, region, commands, interactive, kill-text

I am trying to make emacs function somewhat like sublime text, where `C-x` cuts text that is selected and cuts the whole line when nothing is selected. I got the full-line cut to work using

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") 'kill-whole-line)
```

but I'm not sure how to get `C-w`'s functionality (`kill-region`) to happen when text is selected and then use `C-x`. Is there a way to say something like

```lisp
(if region-selected
    ('kill-region)
  ('kill-whole-line))
```

(And yes, I know I'm rebinding `C-x`, but I'm sick of trying to switch mental muscle memory modes from sublime text to terminal editing.)

Comment: You might be interested checking out [wakib-keys](https://github.com/darkstego/wakib-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To invoke a function, don't quote it: **`(kill-whole-line)`**, not `('kill-whole-line)`.
2. You're looking for function `use-region-p`, so **`(use-region-p)`**, not `region-selected`. (There is no predefined variable `region-selected`.)
3. You need to pass functions the arguments they require. So **`(kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)`**.
4. If you want it to be a function then define it, giving it a name, with `defun`.
5. If you want it to be a command, so you can bind it to a key, then give it an `interactive` spec: **`(interactive)`**.

```lisp
(defun my-kill-cmd ()
  (interactive)
  "Kill region if it's active and nonempty.  Else kill whole line."
  (if (use-region-p)
      (kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (kill-whole-line)))
```

---

To learn more:

- Use `C-h f kill-region` to see what it does and what args it expects.  Likewise, `region-beginning`, `region-end`, `interactive` (a special form), and `defun` (a macro).
- Spend some time with the manual *"An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp"*.  Use `C-h i`, then choose `Emacs Lisp Intro`. When in the manual, you can use `i` to look things up in the Index, using completion. E.g., `i interactive RET`.

---

You probably don't want to bind your command to `C-x`, as that's a prefix key in vanilla Emacs. Better to choose another key.  For example:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") 'my-kill-cmd)
```